# SpringBootTest: how to use application-test.yaml and inherit missing values from application.yaml

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I am trying to run an integration test using the annotations :

`@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
 @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT) 
 @ActiveProfiles({ "test" })`.

The problem I have is that the application loads by using the spring profile "test"
I have two config files:
application.yaml
application-test.yaml

application.yaml contains:

```
xyz:
  list:
  - class-name: com.any.prod.ClassName1
    jndi-name: com/ws/ClassName1
  - class-name: com.any.prod.ClassName2
    jndi-name: com/ws/ClassName2
```

and the other file doesn't contain these values.
these valuer are used by a library that i use, and not directly by my application.

when I load the test with the "test" profile enabled the values from application.yaml are not picked up. If I add the same values to application-test.yaml they are picked up during the binding process.

These are the properties that are picked up:

```
xyz.list[0].class-name: com.any.prod.ClassName1 (loaded from application-test.yaml)
xyz.list[0].jndi-name: com/ws/ClassName1 (loaded from application-test.yaml)
xyz.list[1].class-name: com.any.prod.ClassName2 (loaded from application-test.yaml)
xyz.list[1].jndi-name: com/ws/ClassName2 (loaded from application-test.yaml)
xyz.list (loaded from application.yaml)
```

Unfortunately the last entry makes the validation of the properties fail.
Does anyone has in mind what can I do to solve this mystery?
At this point my understanding of how configuration yaml files are wrong (at least for the testing case - inheritance appears to be working just fine when we deploy our app)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the annotation @TestPropertySource .

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with a similar issue for a good while and was not able to find solutions. I discovered, after much trial and error, that I needed to have the default profile together with my test profile in order to inherit properties.

```
@ActiveProfiles({"default","test"})
```